# Import excel sheet to Tableau but not shown the sheet title automatically

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

When I import the Excel to Tableau, the title of the sheet is not shown automatically, it only shows F1, F2, F3, F4, etc.....

How can I deal with that despite manually rewriting the title?

I tried to modify the Excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

Let me try with my dataset:

Here is what i get when i add my Excel to tableau :

[image: columns are not showing]

To fix this I simply clicked on the "**Data Interpreter**"

[image]

Hope this helps your scenario

Answer (score 0):

From your first image it looks like you just need to delete the first row so that your header row is set as the first row. If you want to do this before you open the file in Tableau you can clean your dataset with `Tableau Prep` or `Python/Pandas`.

Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('YOURFILE')
df = df.iloc[1:]
df.to_csv('OUTPUTFILENAME.csv')
```